# Why is the derivative of the translates of a measure measurable?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis

Let G be a topological group and X a measure space. Let $G \times X \rightarrow X$ be a measurable group action, $\mu$ a $\sigma$-finite measure on $X$, and $g\mu$ (for any $g \in G$) the measure $g\mu(A)= \mu(g^{-1}A)$. Assume that $g\mu$ is always equivalent to $\mu$, that is, $\mu(A)=0$ iff $g\mu(A)=0$ for every measurable $A \subset X$.

Define $$\phi : G \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, (g,x) \mapsto \frac{dg\mu}{d\mu}(x)$$ where $\frac{dg\mu}{d\mu}$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative.

**Why is $\phi$ measurable?**

Comment: What do you mean by $\phi$ being measurable? The group $G$ is not given any measure. (If $G$ were locally compact, one could take the/a Haar measure.) Maybe you mean that $\phi$ is measurable in the variable $x$? Then this is just the statement of Radon-Nikodym theorem. Same question for the notion of a "measurable group action", where $G$ is merely a topological group.

Comment: Of course, maybe you are asking the same question as in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58018/radon-nikodym-derivative-as-a-measurable-function-in-a-product-space?rq=1. Then you should just award your bounty to this user: http://math.stackexchange.com/users/5363/t-b

Comment: @studiosus I mean that G has the sigma algebra of the borel sets, and $G\times X$ has the product sigma algebra.

Comment: @studiosus Thank you.  That question is very similar.  But whats proved is different from the statement that interests me.  For instance, the proof you linked to assumes X is a standard Borel space.

Comment: Why do you think this statement is true or provable in this utter generality? While it seems to be reasonable at first glance, the Radon-Nikodym derivative is subject to a *lot* of constraints which it must fulfill simultaneously. It is not even clear how to make $\phi$ into a well-defined *function* on $G\times X$ without using the axiom of choice: a priori it is only clear that you obtain a map from $G$ to the measurable function *classes* $X \to \Bbb R$, but how do you turn this into a function on $G \times X$? Reading the answers in the in the thread linked by @studiosus (to be continued)

Comment: (continued) it seems quite unlikely that the answerers didn't consider the possibility of doing some general gymnastics before deciding that it is necessary to do some rather hard work.

Comment: @user160629  I don't see the well-definedness issue.  Specifying the class of $f(g,-)$ for all $g$ specifies the class of $f$ (by Fubini's theorem).  In any case, this would also be a problem for the proof to which studiosus linked. You may be right, however, that this is not true in greater generality. The reason I thought it was true is that it is stated on page 325 of the book "Kazhdan's Property (T)" by Bachir Bekka.

Comment: @user160629 Or maybe you would object that there is no "class of $f$" since $G\times X$ has no specified measure.  In that case you may prefer the phrasing in the linked post: There exists measurable $\rho (g,x)$ such that $\rho (g,-)$ is always a derivative of $g\mu$ with respect to $\mu$.